# How would I use vectors to find the ratio?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

$ABC$ is a random triangle. $M$ is from $BC$ and $CM:MB=3:5$. Point $P$ divides $AM$, $AP:PM=2:3$. $BP$ intersects $AC$ in $Q$. Find $AQ:QC$ by using vectors.

[image]

I know how to solve the problem with Minelay or with the centre of mass but I need a solution using the vectors. Personally I strart with basic vectors $\overrightarrow {CB}$ and $\overrightarrow {CA}$ which form my space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix one point $O$ in the plane. (The forthcoming relations do not depend on the choice.)

By definition, the point $M$ satisfies
$$
\overrightarrow {OM}
= 
\frac 38\overrightarrow {OB}
+
\frac 58\overrightarrow {OC}
\ .
$$
Then
$$
\overrightarrow {OP}
= 
\frac 35\overrightarrow {OA}
+
\frac 25\overrightarrow {OM}
=
\frac 35\overrightarrow {OA}
+
\frac 25\cdot \frac 38\overrightarrow {OB}
+
\frac 25\cdot \frac 58\overrightarrow {OC}
\ .
$$
Now for some $\lambda\in \Bbb R$ we have that
$$
\overrightarrow {OQ} = 
\lambda
\overrightarrow {OP}+
(1-\lambda)
\overrightarrow {OB}
\ ,
$$
and this expression does not depend on $\overrightarrow {OB}$ when written in terms of the
vectors $\overrightarrow {OA}$, $\overrightarrow {OB}$, $\overrightarrow {OC}$. This gives the equation in $\lambda$
$$
\frac 25\cdot \frac 38\lambda
+(1-\lambda)=0\ ,
$$
the solution is $\lambda = 20/17$, we plug it in, obtain
$$
\overrightarrow {OP}
= 
\frac{20}{17}
\left(
\frac 35\overrightarrow {OA}
+
\underbrace{\frac 25\cdot \frac 58}_{=1/4}\overrightarrow {OC}
\right)
\ .
$$
As seen, the special value of $\lambda$ and the whole previous step is not needed, 
it is enough to use the weights $\frac 35$ and $\frac 14$, bring them to a common denominator,
$\frac 35=\frac{12}{20}$ and $\frac 14=\frac{5}{20}$ (having the sum...), and the proportion is the one of the numerators.

---

Check using Menelaos for $\Delta ACM$ and the line $QMB$:
$$
\frac{QA}{QC}\cdot
\frac{BC}{BM}\cdot
\frac{PM}{PA}
=1\ ,
$$
explicitly
$$
\frac{QA}{QC}\cdot
\frac{8}{5}\cdot
\frac{3}{2}
=1\ .
$$

Comment: But then how do you find $AQ:QC$?

Comment: In a vectorial representation of the shape $OQ=s\cdot OA+t\cdot OC$ with weights $s,t\in\Bbb R$, i.e. $s+t=1$, (the weights add to give the unit), the place of $Q$ on $AC$ is given by the proportion $t:s$. One can understand this by taking special values for $O$ above, since the relation does not depend on $O$. For instance, if we specialize $O=A$ we get  vectorially instead of $OQ=s\cdot OA+t\cdot OC$ the relation $AQ=s\cdot AA+t\cdot AC$, so $AQ$ collects the $t$.th part of $AC$. One should play with this relation with different weights. (Also with $s=0$, $t=1$ to see which points are so...)